# Splitting and replacing in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, split

I'm trying to split a string and replace just one character within the 
string using a JavaScipt function. My function is as follows..

```
<script>
function test(table, col) {
    var table = document.getElementById(table);
    for (x = 1; x < table.rows.length; x++) {
        var temp = table.rows[x].cells[col].innerHTML;
        table.rows[x].cells[col].innerHTML = .replace('P', 'B');
    }
}
</script>
```

So it is passed the following string `http://ff00.00--p.yos.local:3042/htmltemps/newtest.html` and
I am expecting this result: `http://ff00.00--b.yos.local:3042/htmltemps/newtest.html`. But I get this: 
`b/htmltemps/newtest.html`. Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: It should be `temp.replace('P','B')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "http://ff00.00--p.yos.local:3042/htmltemps/newtest.html";
var res = str.replace("--p", "--b");
```

Note: There is no need to use split().

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExo object with case insensitive flag `i`.

```js
function replaceTexts(tableId, columnIndex) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.rows, function(row) {
    var cell = row.cells[columnIndex];
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("P", "gim"), 'b');
  });
}

replaceTexts('table', 0);
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      http://ff00.00--p.yos.local:3042/htmltemps/newtest.html
     </td>
    <td>
      http://ff00.02--p.yos.local:3042/htmltemps/newtest2.html
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Also notice that **p** in **http** gets replaced. This is probably not desired so I would recommend you to remove scheme part (*http*).